# Pylint in Sublime Text 3 constantly pop a alert dialog: pylint not found at "lint.py"

Tags: python, pylint, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with Package Control

A few days ago I installed Pylint by Package Control
But it not work, and this alert dialog jumps out as long as I open Sublime Text 3

[image: pylint not found at "lint.py"]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have pylint installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation of Pylinter, it specifically says:

> ** Pylint needs to be installed separately!!! **

So if you have only just installed the Pylinter package using the Sublime package manager, then you probably haven't installed Pylint. You can simply install it using pip (if you don't have pip installed check this out: [How can I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)):

```
pip install pylint
```

or

```
pip3 install pylint
```

Once that's installed you may need to change the path value in the Pylinter configuration file so that it points to the correct path.

Comment: Oh, I find what's going on. I got Python 3.3 and Python 2.7 in same time. and I forget install pylint in Python 3.3